# What noun describes the state of an accident survivor? Infirmity, or weakness?

Tags: nouns, synonyms

I cannot think of a proper noun to describe the physical state of someone who survived an encounter with a bear.

He is walking with a severe limp, and has wounds in his back, and his calf.

Therefore, could his condition be named an ***infirmity*** or rather ***weakness***, ***decrepitude***, ***feebleness***? I know that these are mainly used to refer to long time illing people or elders who only stay in bed.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Was it a recent mauling or is this a chronic result?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo a *chronic* mauling?  I think this person needs to stay out of the woods.  :)

Comment: on his back and calf, and not  in his back and calf.

Comment: It is "on" indeed. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say the mauling victim was **maimed** and partially **crippled** if these injuries are permanent.

Answer (score 2):

A person walking with a severe limp with wounds (or injuries to) on his back and calf would be called an invalid (as Andrew said) or disabled.

He has been or is **disabled** by his injuries. [verb]

He  has a **disability** caused by them. [noun]

He is **physically impaired** or has physical impairments. [verb and noun]

[disable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disable)
[impair](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impair)

Comment: This is a good answer, but be aware that "disabled" usually implies *permanent* and *severe* injury like loss of a limb or paralysis.  *Impaired* is better to describe temporary injuries.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this person an *invalid*:

> [**Invalid**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/invalid) (n): *A person made weak or disabled by illness or injury.*
>
> After her terrible accident, she spent the rest of her life as an **invalid**.

Note the difference in pronunciation between [this word](https://vocaroo.com/i/s0qJdHIwgjYe) and the adjective [*invalid*](https://vocaroo.com/i/s0CJSks0tJ26) (meaning "not valid").  Here the accent is on the first syllable.

Comment: Welcomed suggestion! *Fragility* made it in this particular idea. Notwithstanding, your example is a good "synonym" (invalidity) that I happen to use in other text. The extra info it's very much useful. Thanks!

Comment: @sad  "fragile" and "frail" are not really the best words for this context.  I highly recommend waiting for other users' input before deciding on a particular answer.

Comment: Yes, he is an invalid. In other words, he is not well.

Comment: I shall use *invalidity* thereby. I have stared at it for good seconds till it less seemed too "strong" of a choice to my eyes. :)

Comment: @sad  *invalidity* is not in common use.  Also, I agree *invalid* might be too strong.  Is there a reason you don't like the typical *injured*, *hurt*, or *wounded*?

Comment: I wanted to express the idea that he had put an end to his thoughts and worries  overwhelming his mind, because they were bringing in/drawing in *invalidity* (which I finally chose to use after changing the context a little). Meaning, he was able to save himself hobbling away from there, but if he continued worrying and thinking about his condition, he would lose all his strength, becoming an invalid.

Comment: @sad  You should probably ask that as a separate question.  There may be more elegant ways in English to express the sentiment than trying to force it into a single word.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word, '**frailness** or **'fragile**'? This gives the impression that he looks **poor**, **wounded** and given the bear, associates with **ripped clothing** as the homeless. Could also add '**ragged**' but I'm not sure this will fit with the sentence provided.

> "... **Physically weak** or delicate: an invalid's frail body; in **frail health**.

Comment: *Frailness* or *fragility* would do, I believe. As for the ripped clothes, that is expressly mentioned, alongside his condition. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, thought ragged was a bit of a throwaway. I hope the first ones give you some ideas though, best of luck!

Comment: It's been welcomed. Every suggestion can be useful in some other context. All the best!

Comment: I feel that "frail" (and the related "fragile") is commonly used for *physical appearance* or *illness* rather than the consequence of *injury*. e.g.  *"Amid many sufferings, however, and frequent attacks of sickness, he manfully pursued his course; nor was it till his **frail** body, torn by many and painful diseases ... that his indomitable spirit relinquished the conflict."*  It's the right direction, but not the right idiom.